# Object is NULL after using new

Tags: php, object

I have this small error i can't get my head around. I kept getting the following error:

```
Warning: Creating default object from empty value
```

And i figured out it is because $newkey is NULL, What i don't understand is why it is null after i assign it?

```
$newKey = new AccessKey;
$newkey->_token = $data[0]['token'];
$newKey->_id = $data[0]['id'];
$newKey->_workforceid = $data[0]['workforce'];
```

The class itself looks like this

```
class AccessKey
{
    private $_id = -1; 
    private $_token = "";
    private $_workforceid = -1;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Check your casing. You instantiate it as `$newKey` (capital `K`) but are using `$newkey` (small `$key`) later on.

Comment: It's likely the issue is the variable name casing @MagnusEriksson points out, or it's not evident with the information provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Issue #1**
Check your casing.

You instantiate it as `$newKey` (capital `K`) but are using `$newkey` (small `k`) later on.

**Issue #2**
As @JaredFarrish mentioned, you also need to change the properties from `private` to `public` if you're going to set the properties outside the class.

Comment: Not to mention it shows setting private properties directly, which is not going to work.

Comment: ... or use `__construct()` to set variables, or use full setters/getters, or magic `__set()`. Making them public is not a given, it depends on the use case.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$newKey = new AccessKey;
$newKey->_token = $data[0]['token'];
$newKey->_id = $data[0]['id'];
$newKey->_workforceid = $data[0]['workforce'];
```

instead of this

```
$newKey = new AccessKey;
$newkey->_token = $data[0]['token'];
$newKey->_id = $data[0]['id'];
$newKey->_workforceid = $data[0]['workforce'];
```

The problem is `$newkey` is different to `$newKey`

After if you want to set property class you need to change `private` to `public` if you want to set It out of the class

[**DEMO**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/56384cea8ef276c9014bc9827417f62386e7eeb9)

Comment: Try again: https://3v4l.org/SQCSQ Those are also all private, so setting the properties that way won't do anything but throw errors.

Comment: PHP allows for both with or without `()`. It doesn't matter one bit. It's the variable name that's wrong.

Comment: I'm running the code inside a static function inside the class, i just didn't wanted to overcomplicate the question. I tried changing to () but it didn't make any difference

Comment: try with my new update and check the demo link please @user3027185